# After pushing ActiveAdmin app to Heroku, DB empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, activeadmin

I had a working Active Admin app working on my local server, but after pushing to Heroku all my database tables are empty. I tried running `heroku run rake db:migrate` and then `heroku restart` but these both accomplished nothing. The tables are there, but they are empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your Heroku app have the same database as local then you would you need to push your local database via `heroku db:push` to Heroku. This will replace the contents of the tables on Heroku with your local copy so use it carefully.

EDIT: `heroku db:push` is now `heroku pg:push`, the former is deprecated.